# How to reset form to its default values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have 5 search filters, one is text-field-tag, 2 are bootstrap multiple select dropdowns and 2 are from date and to date implemented using datetimepicker. I need to have a reset button to reset the values to the default values(values populated during pageload). Can someone kindly help me

I have a html, controller and js file implemented in ruby on rails.

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_tag({controller: "fraud_search", action: "search"}, method: "post", style: "margin-bottom: 20px;", id: "fraud_search_crit_form") do %>
<div class="row" style="padding:10px;">

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="fraud_order_id">Order ID</label><br>
    <div class="input-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :fraud_order_id, params[:fraud_order_id], class: 'form-control' %>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <button type="button" class="search_reset" id="fraud_order_id_reset" onclick="resetFraudform(this.id)"><span class="ss-icon ss-delete ss-black-tie-bold"></span></button></span>
      </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <%= label_tag :fraud_status, "Status" %>
    <div class="form-group" id="fraud_status">
      <%= select_tag "fraud_status[]",
                     options_for_select(@fraud_order_statuses.map {|status| [status[:name], status[:id]]}, :selected => @selected_fraud_status),
                     {id: 'fraud_status', class: 'form-control selectpicker', 'multiple' => 'true', 'data-actions-box' => (@fraud_order_statuses.map {|status| [status[:name], status[:id]]}.size > 1), 'data-selected-text-format' => 'count > 2', 'data-count-selected-text' => 'All'} %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">
    <%= label_tag :stores, "Stores" %>
    <div class="form-group" id="fraud_stores">
      <% stores = @store_list.to_a %>
      <%= select_tag "fraud_store_ids[]",
                     options_for_select(stores, :selected => @selected_store),
                     {id: 'fraudStoreList', class: 'form-control selectpicker', 'multiple' => 'true', 'data-actions-box' => (stores.size > 1), 'data-selected-text-format' => 'count > 3'} %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <%= label_tag :fraudStartDate, "From Date (" + Time.now.in_time_zone(@timezone).strftime('%Z') + ")" %>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class='input-group date' id='fraudStartDate'>
        <%= text_field_tag :fraud_start_date, '', class: 'form-control' %>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-2'>
    <%= label_tag :fraudEndDate, "To Date (" + Time.now.in_time_zone(@timezone).strftime('%Z') + ")" %>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class='input-group date' id='fraudEndDate'>
        <%= text_field_tag :fraud_end_date, '', class: 'form-control' %>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-1">
    <%= hidden_field_tag :fraud_show_results, "true" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :timezone_fraud, @moment_timezone %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :fraud_start_date_utc, params[:fraud_start_date_utc] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :fraud_end_date_utc, params[:fraud_end_date_utc] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :reset_start_date, params[:reset_start_date] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :reset_end_date, params[:reset_end_date] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :page, params[:page] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :per_page, params[:per_page] %>
    <%= label_tag "" %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= submit_tag("Search", :id => "fraud_show_results_submit", :class => "btn btn-primary", :name => "fraud_show_results_submit", :remote => true) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="reset-form" value="Reset" />
</div>
  <% end %>
```

```
$('#reset-form').on('click', function()
{
$("#fraud_search_crit_form")[0].reset();
});
```

I need to set values to default. but its empting the fields

Comment: So the issue is that the values remain? I don't think you can reset the form and its values with 1 line, especially when you use different libraries for your inputs (i know that you need to programatically tell bs-select to change its value and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add reset button to inside your form.

```
<button type="reset" value="Reset"> Reset Form </button>
```